# SquishIt MVC - Debug mode, not refreshing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, squishit

We got a MVC project running and we seem to have problem refreshing .less files without actually recycling the pool.

If it was just me, I would not bother with this since everytime I compile, the pool recycle. But, our web integrator doesn't like to rebuild since he doesn't even work within Visual Studio when changing the .less files.

Here's what I do:

- Got SquishIt from Nuget to the latest version;
- Calling Bundle.Css().Add(...).Render() in the Layout.cshtml;
- The csproj is set to compile in debug mode (Configuration Manager);
- Got  in the Web.config file.

I look at almost all entries on the codethinked.com web site and couldn't find what I was looking for. Some people seems to have problems, but not with the file not being regenerated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had an answer from Justin Etheredge on google groups. It's going to be fixed in the version 0.8.3.

http://groups.google.com/group/squishit/browse_thread/thread/6643663dda433a68

Comment: Makes sense, always good to know it wasn't just you, right? Thanks for following up the answer here too!

Answer (score 1):

Try using ForceRelease after your call to .Add

Like this:

```
.Add("~/Content/lessfiles/site.less")
.ForceRelease()
.Render("~/Content/combined_site_#.css")
```

After you make the change to include ForceRelease, do your pool recycle once more to make sure you are looking at a fresh file.

Finally, change your .less file with notepad behind the scenes.
The next refresh of the page should pick the change up.

Comment: Unfortunatly, we already tried that and it doesn't work :/ I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

While not a good solution for production, I found running IISReset locally(if you are running through IIS) to be a good way to force squishit to recognize changes.

Comment: Running with version 1.0.4 (latest at time of writing) this actually worked, which I really doubted as I had also restarted my VM in the meantime which didn't change anything.